# No version number was found in Dev Hub for package id and branch 'x' and version number 0.0.0.LATEST that resolved to build number 214

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, extension, managed-extension, 2gmp

Today I have received the following error which seemed quite ambiguous to me

```
No version number was found in Dev Hub for package id 0HoPACKAGEID000AAA and branch 'x' and version number 0.0.0.LATEST that resolved to build number 214
```

Since I do have a version with such number in `sfdx-project.json` in the current branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error happens in the following case.

1. You have two packages, `Package Base` and `Package Extension`.
2. `Package Extension` depends on `Package Base`, on particular version, for example, `0.0.0.LATEST`.
3. You are trying to create a new version of `Package Extension` with branch parameter with value, for example, of `x`.
4. Released package version of `Base package` was `0.0.0.214`, but was built without specifying `branch` parameter or `branch` parameter was different than `x`.
5. It doesn't matter that the base package version `0.0.0.214` is mentioned in sfdx-project.json file since what it requires, it to have the same value of `branch` parameter for both package base and extension

Comment: I strongly believe this is sfdx bug. You should be able to specify branch attribute for each dependency individually, as well as for your current package (either in sfdx config file or via command line, which has a higher priority). And there should be no restrictions for branch names to match. Registered sfdx issue here (https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/2183) - you may refer to 'Additional information' section there to apply kinda ugly workaround at code base level (note, path would be different for linux ci runners, of course). Let's see what they come back with)